# xautolock doesn't start a second time

Tags: bash

I'll give an example to describe my problem.

```
#!/bin/sh
if (( $# == 1 ))
then
    xmessage "before kill"
    killall xautolock
    xmessage "after kill"

    var=$1
    let "var += 1"

    xautolock -time $var -locker "\"./test1.sh\"" &
    xmessage "after run"

    exit 0
fi
```

The first time I start xautolock from bash:

```
$ xautolock -time 1 -locker "./test1.sh 1" &
```

The option -time means that xautolock will start a program which passed as an argument of the option -locker after 1 minute idle time.

After starting xautolock from bash:

```
$ ps ax | grep -E "xaut|test"
6038 pts/1    S      0:00 xautolock -time 1 -locker ./test1.sh 1
6046 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep -E xaut|test
```

After starting xmessage "before kill" :

```
$ ps ax | grep -E "xaut|test"
6038 pts/1    S      0:00 xautolock -time 1 -locker ./test1.sh 1
6223 pts/1    S      0:00 /bin/sh /home/mhd/Texts/Programming/Programms/test1.sh 1
6240 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep -E xaut|test
```

After starting xmessage "after kill":

```
$ ps ax | grep -E "xaut|test"
6223 pts/1    S      0:00 /bin/sh /home/mhd/Texts/Programming/Programms/test1.sh 1
6373 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep -E xaut|test
```

After starting xmessage "after run":

```
$ ps ax | grep -E "xaut|test"
6223 pts/1    S      0:00 /bin/sh /home/mhd/Texts/Programming/Programms/test1.sh 1
6470 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep -E xaut|test
```

Why isn't xautolock in a list of processes after this step? How to start it a second time in a Bash script?

Answer (score 1):

xautolock closes stdout and stdrerr by default. If you will pass the option "-noclose" to xautolock then it will not close stdout and stdrerr and you can start xautolock a second time in the Bash script. But I don't understand why xautolock will not start a second time in my sample script if it has closed stdout and stderr?